# Como obtener o imprimir los datos de un arreglo dentro de otro arreglo en php

Tags: php

Tengo un cosulta que me devuelve el el siguiente arreglo

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    array(1) {
      ["total"]=>
      string(19) "2018-10-23 10:17:00"
    }
    ["r"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(3) "239"
    }
  }
}
```

A uno lo puedo obtener solo así `$arreglo = [0]['r']['id']`, pero con el otro no puedo hacer lo mismo ya que no esta dentro de r

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo mismo que con lo que hiciste pero tomando el otro indice. Todos los arreglos de php tienen un indice, cuando no se específica uno, php asigna por default uno, generalmente números empezando desde el 0. Por lo que puedes acceder así

```
$elOtroDato = [0][0]['total'];
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta tan pronta, realmente puede arreglar mi error y continuar con mi proyecto, muchas  gracias de verdad              saludos.